# Azure analytics in PowerBI

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, azure-analysis-services

I tried to get data from Azure analytics into PowerBI. So I selected Azure DevOps Server(Boards Only), connected to the server, but when trying to select the data, PowerBI gives the following message error:
[The following project does not exist.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiWxo.png)

I made sure that the collection URL and Team Project are correct. The connection to the server established fine and I can see all the project from the given location. Just when clicking on a specific project I get the error above.

Do you have an idea of what the cause might be ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the Personal Access Token used to connect to the azure devops sever have the access permission. If the Personal access token generated from a user account who doesnot have the access permission to that project. The project will not be able to accessed from PowerBi

If it is because of the lack of permission, you need to get someone who can access to that project to generate a new Personnal Access Token for you.

You can also have the project administrator of that Project to add the user (from whom the original Personal access token was generated) to the project.

Comment: The issue it's not the lack of permission.I have full permission on this project.Thank you though for your answer!